# search my site with the help of google in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i want to search my site with the help of google. search result will show in my page and no google related icon will show as if user will feel the search functionality is internal. how could i implement in asp.net. thanks

Comment: Did any of the responses answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

Ah, you are looking for [Google Site Search](http://www.google.com/sitesearch/).
It provides custom branded, in-page results.

Google's free, slightly striped down version is pretty good too: [Google Custom Search](http://www.google.com/cse/)

Comment: Perfect ... Even I was looking for it... :-)

Comment: @chris Glad to help! My business looked into it a while ago, and the url was fresh in mind.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Google Search API to accomplish that. Here are some examples, how you could do it:

- [ASP.NET web client for Google Web API](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/googlewebclient.aspx)
- [Using the Google search API from ASP.NET](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=E8E8CE970C6AB073)
- [Google Search API implementation in asp.net Tutorial](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1498-google-search-api-implementation-asp-net.aspx)

Comment: That article has an XSS hole.  It needs to HTML-escape its output.